# Fetching data using useEffect() make get requests each miliseconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching a data from an API and setting a state. When I do that process, It makes get requests each millisecond. This problem happens, if I set the dependencies array. I want to make a request when API is updated.

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({ baskets: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((products) => {
        setProducts(products);
      });
  }, [products]);
```

Comment: Why are you adding `products` in your dependency array? You should never have a state in a dependecy array of a useEffect which is changing this state

Comment: your `useEffect` is a infinite loop itself, where you use `products` as dependency and then the result of api call `setProducts` and then trigs the dependency change hence rerun the `useEffect` and repeat.

Comment: why not using a socket for this kind of job, instead of each 1 ms making a request?!

Comment: @MohammadMostafaDastjerdi I do not want to make requests, that was the problem, and you are right. I am new to React, and I will try

Answer (score 1):

Remove the dependency from the useEffect Hook

```
 useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((products) => {
        setProducts(products);
      });
  }, []);
```

Here you are updating results into setProducts and it triggers products state change due to useEffect behaviour, So it'll be called infinety.
Also I suggest you to change

```
.then((result) =>{
   setProducts(result);
})
```

Here, you'll face issues with scope in products.

So your final could should be this :

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setProducts(result);
      });
  }, []);
```

Also As per your below comment, here is the updated sample code with use of useCallback

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState({ baskets: [] });

  const fetchProdcuts = useCallback(() => {
    fetch("/api")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((result) => {
        setProducts(result);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchProdcuts();
  }, [fetchProdcuts]);
```

** call fetchProdcuts method whenever you need to refresh the product lists**

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to fetch data from the API and update `products` with the API response. The implementation is correct, but it's causing an infinite loop.

The loop occurs because the useEffect dependency array includes `products`, signifying that the useEffect should be triggered whenever `products` change.

Here's how the loop unfolds:

1. The component mounts, triggering the useEffect.
2. The fetch call inside the useEffect retrieves data and updates
   products.
3. The useEffect notices that products has changed (due to its presence
   in the dependency array), causing it to run again.
4. The loop repeats, leading to continuous API requests.

To break this loop, you should remove `products` from the useEffect dependency array. By doing so, the useEffect will execute only when the component mounts, avoiding subsequent triggers caused by state changes

```
  const [products, setProducts] = useState({ baskets: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((products) => {
        setProducts(products);
      });
  }, []);
```

I suggest reading about useEffects in [the docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#fetching-data-with-effects).

#### Edit

You can revalidate the `products` state by creating a `fetchProducts` function which you can call after sending a POST to your API.

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState({ baskets: [] });

const fetchProducts = () => {
  fetch("/api")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((products) => {
      setProducts(products);
    });
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetchProducts(); // fetch products when the component mounts
}, []);

const handlePostProducts = () => {
  fetch("/products", {
    method: "POST",
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(() => {
      // revalidate products
      fetchProducts();
    });
};
```

Comment: When I try this solution, When API is updated, the useEffect() is not triggered.

Comment: Check out this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/76881036-gyv8wq?file=/src/App.tsx), is this how you want it to work?

Comment: Yes, but if I make a post request to an API, the component should be fetched from the API again so that I can see my new products on the screen

Comment: Here in such a scenario, you need to build and update your code. You need to remove the code from the useEffect, 
You need to combine your code with useCallback. I've edited the answer with the sample code. Please review that. Hope that helps

Comment: I updated the answer now Mustafa. Is this what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState({ baskets: [] });

useEffect(() => {
  fetch("/api")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((fetchedProducts) => {
      setProducts(fetchedProducts);
    });
}, []);

const updateProducts = () => {
  fetch("/api")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((updatedProducts) => {
      setProducts(updatedProducts);
    });
};
```

Try like this

Comment: It'll create code duplicity. Not a best practice to follow.

Comment: You may be right.